# How to save data from an Action Listener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am using an ActionListener to execute a process and create some arrays and store them in a class that is used in a different section of my code. But the instance of dataArrays is not visible outside of the ActionListener. I tried to declare instance dataArrays outside the ActionListener,  but it is required to be final. I can't have this because the values in the arrays will be changed as the program executes. What do I have to do to be able to access the contents of dataArrays outside of the ActionListener? Here is the code I have.

```
event.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                int[] array1 = null;
                double[] array2 = null;
                
                dataConverter ret = new dataConverter(facade.getCountryChoice(), facade.getStartDate(), facade.getEndDate());
                
                array1= ret.intData();
                array2= ret.doubleData();
        
                //Makes a record of the arrays so they can be used later on
                arrays dataArrays = new arrays(array1, array2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: *But the instance of dataArrays is not visible outside of the ActionListener.* - then don't define it local to the method. Instead define it as an instance variable. Also class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Follow Java conventions.

Comment: It has to be final outside of the ActionListener, but I can't have that because the values in dataArray need to change as the program executes.

Comment: *It has to be final* - no it doesn't. I just suggested it could be an instance variable. *the values in dataArray need to change* - add "setter" methods. That is how you dynamically change text in a text field or text area.

Comment: btw, it's good practice to name classes/interfaces/enums and such with PascalCase, not camelCase